# Unable to load the requested file

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm very new to PHP and I got this error (I use Code Igniter). I noticed that people already asked the same question like mine, but I still dont understand the answer.

`Unable to load the requested file: user_form_v.php`

This is my `add()` function in controller:

```
function add(){
    //set common properties 
    $data['title'] = 'Tambah User baru';
    $data['action'] = site_url('user/add');
    $data['link_back'] = anchor('user/index/', 'Back to User list', array('class'=>'back'));

    $this->_set_rules();
    //run validation
    if($this->form_validation->run() == false){
        $data['message'] = '';
        //set common properties 
        $data['title'] = 'Add new User';
        //$data['message'] = '';
        $data['user']['ID_user'] = '';
        $data['user']['nama'] = '';
        $data['user']['email'] = '';
        $data['user']['active'] = '';
        $data['link_back'] = anchor('user/index/', 'Lihat daftar User', array('class'=>'back'));

        $this->load->view('user_form_v', $data);
    }
```

What's going on here?

**UPDATE**
Sorry theres an extra space in my name so it become user_list_v .php, thats all :D

Comment: the file is in your views folder?

Comment: Add the file into your Views folder and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure it is not in sub folder e.g view/sub-folder/user_form_v.php. If it is your last statement should be

```
$this->load->view('sub-folder/user_form_v',$data);
```

Check for spelling mismatch, read write permissions for 'view' folder.

If you are not using any css file. Make sure you remove those links from header and if you are using them make sure they are at the right place.

Comment: ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
Sorry i just miss type from user_form_v.php to user_form_v .php
Thanks :D